# PHP Processing CSV file separated by semicolon

Tags: php

I've a csv file with the following structure:

```
a; b; c,c c; d
```

When I try to process it, it says offset 2 and 3 are undefined. Took me a while to realize it is caused by the `,` and have no idea how to solve this. If I remove the `,` everything runs fine.

Here's my processing function:

```
function process_csv($file) {

    $file = fopen($file, "r");
    $data = array();

    while (!feof($file)) {
        $csvdata = fgetcsv($file);

        $data[] = explode(';', $csvdata[0]);
    }

    fclose($file);
    return $data;
}
```

Tried `fgetcsv($file);` as `fgetcsv($file, '"');` but didn't help.

Comment: The separator is the third argument to [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your problem is, that `fgetcsv` uses `,` as delimiter by default. If you  change it to `;` you don't need to `explode`.

```
function process_csv($file) {

    $file = fopen($file, "r");
    $data = array();

    while (!feof($file)) {
        $data[] = fgetcsv($file, null, ';');
    }

    fclose($file);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Wow, shame on me! I did everything on a wrong way. This must be the reason why I couldn't find any topic related to my problem :) Thank you very much, now everything works as it should be!

Comment: @Marc, I'd suggest to keep the declaration of $data. first, you are sure that it's initialized correctly, second, if there is no line in the file, the declaration never happens and the return value is null.